# Загрузка интерпретатора

Tags: php

Написал что типа чата, где выводило 1 сообщение потом через 5 секунд `sleep(5)` должно появится второе, но когда я обновляю сайт он грузит 5 секунд и показывает сразу 2 сообщения, как сделать так чтобы в live режиме сообщения появлялись, сначала одно потом другое ?

Comment: sleep нужен для задержки скрипта, а не для вывода.

Comment: @FixiDens Хорошо, тогда как мне сделать так чтобы сообщения выводились последовательно через n время ?

Comment: Для этого AJAX существует, если вы это в браузере делаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Php буферизует вывод. Чтобы вывести содержимое буферов на экран, используйте ob_flush().

Comment: Спасибо огромное!